# Using async/await to get information

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a list that I need to load with product names like:

```
List<string> prodNames= new List<string>();
```

Product data does not exist on my system.  So, I must download them first.

Product data is downloaded one-by-one to local file system.  Downloading a product fires an event handler which I handle and the handler provides the product name I need to add to the list.

I know number of products to get this way at all times, say 5.

I am trying to figure out how do I know when all 5 product names have been added to my list so I can proceed to display them.  Here is the pseudocode

```
List ids = // list of product ids 
List<string> prodNames= new List<string>();  //list to fill with prod names once they are downloaded

this.EventHandler += OnDownloadedProduct; //event fired once each product is downloaded

void GetProducts()
{
  foreach (var id in ids)
  {
     // NOTE that I cannot modify neither downloader object nor GetProduct() 
     // method.  These are not my code but come from a component for which
     // I have no code access.
     downloader.GetProduct(id);  //fires OnDownloadedProduct once product is downloaded
  } 
}

//this event is fired once each product data is downloaded.
// ProductDataArgs is provided to me and I cannot modify it.
void OnDownloadedProduct(object sender, ProductDataArgs e)
{
   // this is where I get product name and add it to the list
   string prodName = e.getProdName();
   prodNames.Add(prodName);
   // <-- I could show prodName here in a message box but that
   // would show one message box for all 5 products.  I don't
   // want that.  I want to show all 5 product names in one
   // message box.
}
```

I need to display all 5 product names in a form or message box.  I could do it in above event but for each product.  This would show 5 message boxes (or forms).  But I need to show them all 5 in a single message box.  So, I need to so something like this in caller:

```
List<string> prodNames = await.GetProducts(ids);
var names = null;
foreach(var prod in prodNames)
{
  names += string.Format("{0}\n");
}
MesageBox.Show(names);
```

**PROBLEM:** The problem I face is that the operation may take time and that I dont know when the list is loaded with all 5 product names (because names are not available in GetProducts method but in OnDownloadedProduct event).

After some research on my own, Tasks/async/await seem to offer solution for this but all examples I have seen so far are not addressing the situation I described above where I depend on an event handler to get what I need (in this case, all 5 product names).

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Kris comment below, I have been able to rewrite my logic into this but it is not working properly:

```
public class ProductRetriver
{
    List<int> ids = new List<int>();  // product ids
    List<string> prodNames = new List<string>();  // product names

    private TaskCompletionSource<List<string>> prodsTask;

    this.EventHandler += OnDownloadedProduct; 

    Task<List<string>> async GetProducts(List<int> _ids)
    {
        ids = _ids;
        prodsTask = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            //PROBLEM: GetProduct() is not awaited, so method will finish
            //before list is filled.  Also, it seem to add duplicates for
            //some reason to the list.  I cannot modify the method as it is
            //not code available to me.
            downloader.GetProduct(id);  //fires OnDownloadedProduct 
        }
        return prodNames;
    }

    //this event is fired once each product data is downloaded
    void OnDownloadedProduct(object sender, ProductDataArgs e)
    {
        // this is where I get product name and add it to the list
        string prodName = e.getProdName();
        prodNames.Add(prodName);
        if (prodNames.Count == ids.Count)
        {
            prodsTask.SetResult(prodNames);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you actually want Reactive Extensions, which work with streams of data.

Comment: You could expose a custom event that you raise when the two list counts are equal (which you'd check in `OnDownloadedProduct`).  Then consuming code could subscribe to that event much like how you subscribe to the event in the code you have.

Comment: @David  Thanks, I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why not have a check at the end of `OnDownloadedProduct` like `if (prodNames.Count >= 5) AlertMe()`?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what is this downloader and where it comes from, if eventhandler is out side downloader try this

```
 public class ProductRetriver
{

    List<int> ids = new List<int>();
    List<string> prodNames = new List<string>();  //list to fill with prod names once they are downloaded
    private TaskCompletionSource<List<string>> prodsTask;
        this.EventHandler += OnDownloadedProduct; //event fired once each product is downloaded

        Task<List<string>> async GetProducts(List<int> _ids)
    {
        ids = _ids;
        prodsTask = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            downloader.GetProduct(id);  //fires OnDownloadedProduct once product is downloaded
        }

    }

    //this event is fired once each product data is downloaded
    void OnDownloadedProduct(object sender, ProductDataArgs e)
    {
        // this is where I get product name and add it to the list
        string prodName = e.getProdName();
        prodNames.Add(prodName);
        if (prodNames.Count == ids.Count)
        {
            prodsTask.SetResult(prodNames);
        }
    }
}
```

if eventhandler is a part of downloader you can do this

```
Task<List<string>> async GetProducts(List<int> ids)
    {
        List<string> prodNames = new List<string>();

        downloder.EventHandler += (s, e) => {

            string prodName = e.getProdName();
            prodNames.Add(prodName);
            if (prodNames.Count == ids.Count)
            {
                prodsTask.SetResult(prodNames);
            }
        };
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            downloader.GetProduct(id);  //fires OnDownloadedProduct once product is downloaded
        }

        return prodNames;

    }
```

you can call this like this

```
Products = await getproducts(ids);
```

Comment: I get "GetProducts must have return type"

Comment: Task<List<string>> that's the return type right ? just swap it
async  Task<List<string>>  GetProducts(List<int> ids)

Comment: The event handler is outside of Downloader so I am referring to your first example above. The problem (in both cases though) is that the call downloader.GetProduct(id) is called without await. That means, the method will return ProdNames before it finishes all downloads. I updated my question to show what I have so far based on your answer.  Thank you

Comment: try await Task.Run(()=> downloader.GetProduct(id));

Comment: @dbnex14 one thing to note, if downloader.getproduct(id) is fireandforget method, you don't need to worry right ?  as the control will return to OnDownloadedProduct you don't need to wait as the task will wait until you sent the result on the task right ? I mean prodsTask starts in getproducts method in this method you call downloader.getproduct(id) ids.count times and OnDownloaded will be called ids.count times so for the last file download complete prodsTask result is set so until then it will wait, right ?

Comment: Cant use await Task.Run(() => downloader.GetProduct(id)); since GetProduct(id) is not an async method.  I get "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier".  Also, in your very 1st solution, GetProducts() return prodNames list but it has nothing in it and I believe it is because it is not awaiting something.  Are you saying  it should return prodsTask instead?

Comment: if you look at my code both have Task<List<string>> and wait operator, are you missing anything or I am missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand, you don't need received result from downloader.GetProduct(id) ? If so - for what you want awaiting ? Just create list of tasks and wait while them all finished like this:

```
public class ProductRetriver
{
List<int> ids = new List<int>();  // product ids
List<string> prodNames = new List<string>();  // product names

private TaskCompletionSource<List<string>> prodsTask;

this.EventHandler += OnDownloadedProduct; 
public static List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
Task<List<string>> async GetProducts(List<int> _ids)
{
    ids = _ids;
    prodsTask = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {

       TaskList.Add(downloader.GetProduct(id));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
    return prodNames;
}

//this event is fired once each product data is downloaded
void OnDownloadedProduct(object sender, ProductDataArgs e)
{
    // this is where I get product name and add it to the list
    string prodName = e.getProdName();
    prodNames.Add(prodName);
    if (prodNames.Count == ids.Count)
    {
        prodsTask.SetResult(prodNames);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As I mentioned, the downloader.GetProduct(id) is provided to me and I can modify neither downloader object nor GetProduct() method.  In your code above, like TaskList.Add(downloader.GetProduct(id)); errors with "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'my_namespace.ICancellable' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'".  But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: This error mean just type mismatch - if you can give me exact typeof(downloader.GetProduct(int id)) than I can you more exactly suggestion ... But without full information nobody can give you exact answer ;-)